# iOS vice versa import workaround

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to find answer for my question but failed.

Can i do any workaround to let two classes import each other.

```
#import "classB.h"
@interface classA : NSObject
{
    classB bObject;
}




#import "classA.h"
@interface classB : NSObject
{
   classA aObject;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of actually importing your headers in your headers, use `@class` to make a forward class declaration:

```
@class classB;
@interface classA : NSObject
{
    classB bObject;
}


@class classA;
@interface classB : NSObject
{
   classA aObject;
}
```

This just tells the compiler that `classA` and `classB` are classes, without actually loading any of the interfaces.

If you use any of `classA`'s methods in `classB`, you'll need the `classA` interface in `classB`'s implementation, in which case you can just import `classB.h` in `classA.h` (or vice versa).